# RequestIntercepor for a specific FeignClient

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a RequestInterceptor where I  automatically copy an AccessToken from OAuth2ClientContext into the RequestTemplate's header so that the internal services are seamlessly calling one another with the same AccessToken that came from the mobile device that started the scenario.
And that's how we manage services methods authorization. 
This is the interceptor code:

```
public class FeignOAuthInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    public FeignOAuthInterceptor (OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
        this.oauth2ClientContext = oauth2ClientContext;
    }
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        if (!template.headers().containsKey(PropertyBagFilter.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER) && oauth2ClientContext.getAccessTokenRequest().getExistingToken() != null) {
            template.header(PropertyBagFilter.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, String.format("%s %s", PropertyBagFilter.BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE,
                    oauth2ClientContext.getAccessTokenRequest().getExistingToken().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the @Beans configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public OAuth2ClientContext oAuth2ClientContext (){
        return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor feignOAuthInterceptor(OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext) {
        return new FeignOAuthInterceptor(oauth2ClientContext);
    }
    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails(){
        return new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    }
```

The problem is that there are different FeignClients and part of them are for 3rd party services, such as a services which we use for SMS texts and I don't want to send the AccessToken there.

How can I determine inside the RequestInterceptor what FeignClient it came from?